# Adding a file to a specific path in a 7-zip archive using SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, .net, archive, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I am trying to add a file stored on my local disk to a 7-zip archive using `SevenZipSharp` and the `7z.dll`. This file should be added to some path `\a\b\c\...` inside the archive. However, the `CompressFiles` method of SevenZipSharp's `SevenZipCompressor` does not seem to provide an overload for which the destination can be set.

How do I add a file to a specific path in a 7-zip archive using SevenZipSharp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create in a temp folder your desired folder structure and the use the following:

```
SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.PreserveDirectoryRoot = true;
compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
compressor.CompressDirectory(@"C:\Test", "ppp.zip");
```

In my example, I created many subfolders under "C:\Test", and as a result, I got the same folder structure in the zip file starting with root "\test..."